# gtktreeview(c code): find the iter of the row just below header

Tags: treeview, gtk, row

Below is a `gtktreeview` built by `GtkListStore` in **GTK+** by C code. The first row is the header built by **gtk_cell_renderer_text_new**. The rows followed are the contents.

Assuming that there are lots of rows, when scrolling down, how can I find the `iter` of the row **just below header**? For example, in the initial, the iter of the row just below header is 0. When scrolling down, the iter of the row just below header could be 3 or 78 or whatever. Please note that the row just below header might **not** be selected.

I don't know:

First, what signal is connected with the action "scrolling down"?

Second, how to find the row just below header?

Please help. Thank you.

```
+----------+-----------+------------+----------------------+
|row ID    |title 2    |title 3     |title 4               |
|          |           |            |                      |
+----------+-----------+------------+----------------------+
|          |           |            |                      |
|    1     |           |            |                      |
+----------+-----------+------------+----------------------+
|          |           |            |                      |
|    2     |           |            |                      |
+----------+-----------+------------+----------------------+
|          |           |            |                      |
|    3     |           |            |                      |
+----------+-----------+------------+----------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GtkTreeview implements [GtkScrollable](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/unstable/GtkScrollable.html), so you can do `gtk_scrollable_get_vadjustment ()` and connect to the [`value-changed`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/unstable/GtkAdjustment.html#GtkAdjustment-value-changed) signal on the adjustment.

For question #2, take a look at [`gtk_tree_view_get_visible_range ()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/unstable/GtkTreeView.html#gtk-tree-view-get-visible-range): the start_path should be path of the first even slightly visible row.

Answer (score 1):

According to jku's answer, the solution to the issue in detail is:

```
void treeview_vadjustment_changed (GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data)
{
  GtkTreePath *start_path;

  if(gtk_tree_view_get_visible_range(treeview, &start_path, NULL))
  {
    gchar *str;
    GtkTreeIter start_iter, iter;
    GtkTreeModel *model = gtk_tree_view_get_model(treeview);
    if(gtk_tree_model_get_iter(model, &start_iter, start_path) && ACC_truss_get_truss_weight_iter (model, start_iter, &iter))
    {
      int who;
      GtkWidget *window = g_object_get_data(G_OBJECT(treeview), "parent_window");

      gtk_tree_model_get(model, &iter, TRUSS_MEM_AXIS_NAME, &str, -1);
      who = GPOINTER_TO_INT(g_object_get_data(G_OBJECT(model), "which_truss"));
      switch(who)
      {
    case 0:
      gtk_entry_set_text((GtkEntry *)g_object_get_data(G_OBJECT(window), "ACC_SDD_main_truss_curr"), str);  
      break;
    case 1:
      gtk_entry_set_text((GtkEntry *)g_object_get_data(G_OBJECT(window), "ACC_SDD_second_truss_curr"), str);  
      break;
      }
      g_free(str);
    }
  }
  gtk_tree_path_free(start_path);
}

  .
  .
  store = gtk_list_store_new(TRUSS_NUMS_MEM_SEC, G_TYPE_STRING, G_TYPE_STRING, G_TYPE_STRING, G_TYPE_STRING, G_TYPE_STRING, G_TYPE_STRING, G_TYPE_STRING, G_TYPE_STRING, G_TYPE_STRING, G_TYPE_STRING, G_TYPE_STRING, G_TYPE_STRING, G_TYPE_STRING, G_TYPE_STRING);
  switch(who)
  {
    case 0:
      g_object_set_data(G_OBJECT(window), "ACC_main_truss_SDD_mem_tree_store", store);
      break;
    case 1:
      g_object_set_data(G_OBJECT(window), "ACC_second_truss_SDD_mem_tree_store", store);
      break;
  }

  model = GTK_TREE_MODEL(store);

  /* create tree view */
  treeview = gtk_tree_view_new_with_model(model);
  g_object_set_data(G_OBJECT(treeview), "parent_window", window);
  gtk_tree_view_set_rules_hint(GTK_TREE_VIEW(treeview), TRUE);
/*  gtk_tree_view_set_search_column(GTK_TREE_VIEW(treeview), COLUMN_DESCRIPTION);*/
  ACC_member_treeview_header_truss (GTK_TREE_VIEW(treeview), who);
  g_object_unref(model);
  gtk_widget_show(treeview);
  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(scrolled_window), treeview);

  vadjustment = gtk_tree_view_get_vadjustment(GTK_TREE_VIEW(treeview));
  g_signal_connect(vadjustment, "value-changed", G_CALLBACK(treeview_vadjustment_changed), treeview);
  .
  .
```